# PHP POST: Form keeps submitting when I reload the page

Tags: php, forms, post, reload

I have this code:

```
<div id="loginform">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
        <label style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; width: 195px;" for="name">Upload Image: </label>
        <input style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; width: 195px;" type="file" name="file">
        <input style="font-family: Sans-serif;" type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enter']))
{
    echo "
        <div style=\"display: flex; height: 150px; box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px #bebebe;\">
            <img height=\"150px;\" src=\"https://i.ibb.co/Lr07dyk/myQR.png\">
            <span style=\"margin-top: 5px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 25px;\">Scan the QR code on another device <b>
                    <i>
                        <u>or</u>: 
                    </i>
                </b>
                <br>
                <span style=\"font-size: 16px;\">On another device, go to <a target=\"_top\" href=\"\">this website on another device</a> to view your images. </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    ";
}
?>
```

But when I reload the page I still see
"On another device, go to this website on another device to view your images."
It doesn't go away.

Comment: When you reload the page are you resubmitting the form action? (Unrelated but if you used single quotes for the echo encapsulation you wouldn't need to escape all the double quotes in the HTML... it also would be un-noticeably faster because string won't need to be parsed for variables/special chars)

Answer (score 0):

this code will solve your problem, i test it with your code (add it at the top of your code)

```
<script>
  if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
</script>
```

Good luck